# C# documentation: <see> or <seealso> for a operation

Tags: c#, documentation

I'm just writing some code comments and now i would like the [`<see>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/acd0tfbe.aspx) or the `<seealso>` tag to link another method. How can I do that? I just saw this done for classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example:

```
<see cref="Namespace.Class.Method{T}(string,string)"/>
```

This references the method named `Method` with one generic parameter in the class `Class` in the namespace `Namespace`. It references the overload of `Method` that accepts two string parameters.

If there is only one method with that name in the class, you can also use `Namespace.Class.Method{T}`, i.e. you don't need to specify the parameter types.

If the documentation is for a method in class `Class` you don't need to specify the namespace and class.

Basically: It follows the same scoping rules as in normal code.